# uikit - how to make long list of tabs go into overflow rather than underneath

Tags: html, css, uikit

So right now, if I have a long list of tabs, rather than overflowing and creating a scrollbar, it just appends the new tabs underneath, stacking them on top of each other. I don't like this design and I was wondering if there was a way to allow/force them to overflow.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  $("#tabs").append(`
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  `);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.34/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.34/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.34/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='tabs' class="uk-tab" data-uk-tab="{connect:'#content'}" style="overflow-x: scroll; ">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `flex-wrap: nowrap` and `max-width` to `#tabs`, like:

```
#tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 10000px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  $("#tabs").append(`
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  `);
}
```

```css
#tabs {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.34/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.34/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.34/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='tabs' class="uk-tab" data-uk-tab="{connect:'#content'}" style="overflow-x: scroll; ">
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!